# Mouse Over Text with Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

[image]I have a dynamic table built with **datatables**. How can I set a mouse over text over the elements? I would like to have a different text for each column, and for the first column i would like to have a different text for each row id, the text coming from my **php json** file.

**My js code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#doentes').DataTable({
     "ajax" :  "functions/getDiagnosticoGeral.php",

     "columns" : [ 
     {
      "data" : "id"
 }, {
      "data" : "abandonos"
 }, {
      "data" : "canal_1"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_1"
 }, {
      "data" : "venda_1"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_preco_1"
 }, {
      "data" : "canal_2"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_2"
 }, {
      "data" : "venda_2"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_preco_2"
 }, {
      "data" : "canal_3"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_3"
 }, {
      "data" : "venda_3"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_preco_3"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_views"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_frete_sp"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_frete_rj"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_frete_mg"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_frete_pr"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_frete_rs"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_prazo_sp"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_prazo_rj"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_prazo_mg"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_prazo_pr"
 }, {
      "data" : "dif_prazo_rs"
 }, {
      "data" : "requisicoes_cnova"
 }, {
      "data" : "requisicoes_b2w"
 }, {
      "data" : "requisicoes_walmart"
 }, {
      "data" : "requisicoes_shopfacil"
 }, {
      "data" : "requisicoes_magazine"
 }, {
      "data" : "nota"
 }, {
      "data" : "tipo"
 }, {
      "data" : "janela"
 }],

 "scrollX": true,

 "orderFixed": [[ 31, "asc"],[ 32, "asc"],[ 2, "asc"],[ 3, "desc" ]]
});                
});
```

**My table:**

```
<table id="doentes" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Abandonos</th>
                          <th>Canal 1</th>
                          <th>Pedidos</th>
                          <th>Venda</th>
                          <th>Preço</th>
                          <th>Canal 2</th>
                          <th>Pedidos</th>
                          <th>Venda</th>
                          <th>Preço</th>
                          <th>Canal 3</th>
                          <th>Pedidos</th>
                          <th>Venda</th>
                          <th>Preço</th>
                          <th>Views</th>
                          <th>Frete SP</th>
                          <th>Frete RJ</th>
                          <th>Frete MG</th>
                          <th>Frete PR</th>
                          <th>Frete RS</th>
                          <th>Prazo SP</th>
                          <th>Prazo RJ</th>
                          <th>Prazo MG</th>
                          <th>Prazo PR</th>
                          <th>Prazo RS</th>
                          <th>Req CNova</th>
                          <th>Req B2W</th>
                          <th>Req Walmart</th>
                          <th>Req Shopfacil</th>
                          <th>Req Magazine</th>
                          <th>Nota</th>
                          <th>Tipo</th>
                          <th>Janela</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                         <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Abandonos</th>
                          <th>Canal 1</th>
                          <th>Pedidos</th>
                          <th>Venda</th>
                          <th>Preço</th>
                          <th>Canal 2</th>
                          <th>Pedidos</th>
                          <th>Venda</th>
                          <th>Preço</th>
                          <th>Canal 3</th>
                          <th>Pedidos</th>
                          <th>Venda</th>
                          <th>Preço</th>
                          <th>Views</th>
                          <th>Frete SP</th>
                          <th>Frete RJ</th>
                          <th>Frete MG</th>
                          <th>Frete PR</th>
                          <th>Frete RS</th>
                          <th>Prazo SP</th>
                          <th>Prazo RJ</th>
                          <th>Prazo MG</th>
                          <th>Prazo PR</th>
                          <th>Prazo RS</th>
                          <th>Req CNova</th>
                          <th>Req B2W</th>
                          <th>Req Walmart</th>
                          <th>Req Shopfacil</th>
                          <th>Req Magazine</th>
                          <th>Nota</th>
                          <th>Tipo</th>
                          <th>Janela</th>
                         </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I tried some solutions for similar questions but neither seemed to work for me.

Comment: Can you tell us your desired change?

Comment: I want a mouse over text on each one of the table columns.

Comment: You mean to say if I hover mouse on `<th>Id</th>` then the tool tip should show `ID`?

Comment: When the mouse hover each of the Id elements I show a different text.

Comment: Can you give me an example what you need to achieve ?

Comment: I added an image with some examples of the hover texts, does that help?

Comment: I checked that image. So the title for each cell is little different. And its defination is not there even in the json data. So can you give me that details like, for which cell/column what title should be shown ?

Comment: I solved with the solution from Anestis Selmani. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly you want some kind of tooltip on hover of every cell. In order to do that you need to change you cell content to html elements that allow the preview of the title. 
For example the content of the cell Abandonos should be something like that:

```
<th><span title='The title you wish to show on hover'>Abandonos</span></th>
```

Comment: From the image I understood that he probably wanted to show some text on hover of cell text. Wherever you want the same effect you could create an element that has the attribute title and the title will appear on hover by default. On hover of entire rows you should probably use tooltips that you should position, design and initiate.

Comment: I didnt use span direcly in the <th> in the html. I added to my output from my php file and it worked. Now Im trying to work it with the bootstrap tooltip.

Comment: To use it with the bootstrap tooltip you should add to the span the data-toggle="tooltip" attribute and after the datatable is initialized and the cells are html elements with title as I mentioned before you should initialize the tooltip by this: $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip({ container: 'body' }); . Careful because if you initialize the tooltip in document ready before the elements are rendered (since you rendering the data in document ready) the tooltips won't show. This is because there aren't yer any elements with that attribute yet rendered.

Comment: The scripts follow some kind of order? I put  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: 'body' }); below the datatables function and i have data-toggle="tooltip" in my row items but it is still not showing.

Comment: The initialization of the tooltip via $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: 'body' }); should be called be called after the rendering of the elements. If you render the span elements with the data-toggle="tooltip" in document ready the exactly after you should initialize the tooltip. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to work with childs in css3. here is the link where you can very well lern the way to do it https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Answer (score 0):

What I do is showing extra text directly on the cell on hover :
Instead of title i've used a data attr but you can do the same with title attr
I put my extra text on the my attr

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```css
.rcDescription_datatable{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .yavuz_Description_datatable:hover{
        color: blue;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .yavuz_Description_datatable:hover:after{
        content:attr(data-restOfDesc);
        color: blue;
        font-style: italic;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Yavuzcan</td>
                <td><span class="yavuz_Description_datatable" data-restOfDesc="sur le principe du wiki. Ce projet vise à offrir un contenu librement réutilisable, objectif et vérifiable, que chacun peut modifier et améliorer.">Wikipédia est un projet d’encyclopédie collective en ligne, universelle, multilingue et fonctionnant</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nicolas</td>
                <td><span class="yavuz_Description_datatable" data-restOfDesc="my  text that continues">My main text goes to here and if you hover it extra text will be shown </span></td>
            </tr>
           
        </tbody>
       
    </table>
```